# Laravel - Homestead issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I read tutorials on net and try to start using laravel but first I need to install homestead... I do everything like I read but pease help me with this:

[MY SCREENSHOOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Xlq.png)

> why at every command I get 'php' is not reconizes as an internal ...
>   ...

Please help, i'm new to homestead and laravel, before thi question I try almost everything...
Why I get this messages at CMD? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System can't find your php to run scripts.
Problem is that you need to install php to your windows.
If you already installed, add folder with your php to PATH variable.

Comment: ok that was a problem but I install homstead and now  get: 'homestead' is not reconized as an internal or external command ... ... WHY?

Comment: at first check if this command will work fine 'php -v'. If it isn't - do what I say earlier.
second - how you try to run homestead? To make it works from everywhere you must add composer packages binary folder add to path, and then install homestead globally by composer. Or go to directory where you installed homestead, and run `./homestead' command.
It also want's ruby, as I remember.

Comment: php -v works fine but I also write this: http://i.imgur.com/vZbWeGF.png, please see image and everything what I do... but command homestead dont work!

Comment: Add your ~/.composer/vendor/bin to your PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your vagrant box already exists.

Start again from the first step, but now use

```
vagrant box add --force laravel/homestead
```

Comment: but I laredy run vagrant and choose virtualbox as option ... now as I see I need again wait to download virtualbox... WHY?

Comment: I also cant start COMPOSER as you can see on the image